# CloneZilla, does exist a simpler method?

Tags: linux, disk, clonezilla

While browsing the web for backing up my disk, I often see CloneZilla in the results. The process seems tricky to me (Live USB, etc). Note: I plan to back up my whole disk (system, root, home, etc.).

I noted: `dd`, `dump(8)`, `fsarchiver` and others. Some are deprecated, others incompatible (I work with Linux Mint). I think `fsarchiver` is quite cool: it can run on a running file system with option `-A`, it accepts many formats, etc.

If I persist with CloneZilla,

- is it convenient for filesystem backup?
- will I need 2 pendrives ? (One for live booting `clonezilla`, the second for getting the backup on it)

Comment: Why does it matter whether or not people like `CloneZilla`? It serves a purpose and I understand it does it satisfactorily. If you have a particular problem that you cannot resolve please update your Question to include that specific issue.

Comment: @ArchiT3K: why yet another question on the same matter https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/211337/linux-best-way-for-cloning-backingup?noredirect=1#comment358021_211337?