# Linux : Best way for cloning/backingup

Tags: linux, linux-mint, backup

I browse various solutions for backing up :

- tar (and his -N option, for incremental tar files)
- dump (and his level feature backing only new files, if wanted)
- fsarchiver
- CloneZilla ...

Starting from one point : I aim to copy my whole disk for 1.backing up 2. clone it to another same virgin machine. Or the same machine (full restore).

What s the best (quick sure) way ?

Comment: I used to do it with `rsync`

Comment: Personal preference. It works in command line and can use `ssh` to connect to a source host. Additionally, it can be used for creating incremental backups if one decided it's necessary in the long run.

Comment: **ssh** is a good point for rsync, note that **rsync** is less gentle about RAM than **dump**. "they are something to use for imaging filesystems, to be used instead of dd(1) or rsync(1), and good enough to backup your laptop to an external disk. Use something like zmanda or bacula if you need more"

Comment: tthank you. Does rsync embed all partitions in one backup ? or do you have to clone each one (boot, fs...) ?

Comment: `rsync` copies requested files just like `scp` or `cp`. It doesn't care about partitions etc. I used `rsync` to make a backup of Linux system running directly on a hardware and restored it inside `VirtualBox`. Just pick directories you will need to make a restore such as `/usr`, `/etc`, `/home`, `/var`, `/root`, `/opt`

Comment: @Arkadiusz Drabczyk : thanks. so you leave the boot away, a bit like dump. Am I right ?

Comment: Right, I wouldn't copy `/boot` directory because it's not necessary to restore system. I have never used `dump` though so I can't say nothing about it. I just know, IIUC, that `rsync` would be the right tool to do the job you want. However, as in everything, it's a matter of personal preference and knowledge of an particular tool. You need to make a decision yourself.

Comment: thanks. I aim to both clone and backup. That's my glitch.

Answer (score -1):

To copy a disk to *an identical disk* use low level command  **dd**. Or use tuned and safe save tools.

Obviously the copied disk have not to be accessed by the system (except dd itself).
*dd* is usually used to make a clone for a bootable disk to another bootable one.

*[Unix doc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_%28Unix%29)*

*[Basic sample](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/19141/clone-a-hard-drive-using-an-ubuntu-live-cd/)*

Comment: I have been said **dd** copy empty space, while **dump** does not. Why not **dump** ?

Comment: *dd* is low level, copy bytes to bytes from disk cylinders, it does not know what it copy. *dump* needs data in a partition. If you need sauvegardes use tools tested and tuned for this operation.

Comment: dump works on ext2/3 filesystems, you asked for a method to clone one disk to another disk.

Comment: thanks  @c-r . does that mean : dd copies all disk partitions (boot, fs, ...) to another disk ? dump does not manage boot partition ?

Comment: @ArchiT3K You have understood : *dd* copy not only partition, but the hooks : all bytes from all cylinders of a disk from byte 0 to the last includ. It is powerful but maipulation errors are desastrous, use shell tuned and tested to manage it.

Comment: [No, don't use `dd`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17295/when-is-dd-suitable-for-copying-data-or-when-are-read-and-write-partial)